# Python Web scraping | How to handle missing elements using try and except so that it prints as Not available if element not is found?

Tags: python, exception, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, try-except

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

import bs4

headers = {'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Brave Chrome/83.0.4103.116 Safari/537.36'}

my_url = 'https://www.jiomart.com/c/groceries/dairy-bakery/dairy/62'



uclient = uReq(my_url)

page_html = uclient.read()

uclient.close()


bs41 = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')


containers = bs41.find_all('div', {'col-md-3 p-0'})
#print(len(containers))


#print(soup.prettify(containers[0]))



for container in containers:
    p_name = container.find_all('span', {'class' : 'clsgetname'})
    productname = p_name[0].text

    o_p = container.find_all('span' , id = 'final_price' )
    offer_price = o_p[0].text


    try:
        ap = container.find_all('strike', id = 'price')
        actual_price = ap[0].text

    except:
        print('not available')

    

    print('Product name is', productname)
    print('Product Mrp is', offer_price)
    print('Product actual price', actual_price)
    
    
    print()
```

> While performing the above code, There is a product which doesn't have
> a actual price and has offer price only.  But other products are
> having both the values.  When I'm trying to handle the exception via
> try and except  by printing 'Not Available' it's not Working.
>
> Rather It's printing it on the first-line as Not Available and it's
> also showing a actual price of rs 35 whereas actual price is null.
>
> How should i deal with these things, so it may help me.

Comment: can I ask what the url is?

Comment: It's a url of a website which has some products, All i wanted was to learn web scraping. So with help of youtube, I'm learning how to scrape data.

Comment: Right, but it's possible there is API which is a more efficient way to web scrape. But can't look if I don't know the site.

Comment: I'm not into api much more, Will get back to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that even if it does not find the element, it still prints `actual_price` which is probably in an outer scope.

You have 2 ways to approach this.

- The 1st is to only print if the element was found, for which you can do:

```py
    try:
        ap = container.find_all('strike', id = 'price')
        actual_price = ap[0].text
        print('Product name is', productname)
        print('Product Mrp is', offer_price)
        print('Product actual price', actual_price)

    except:
        print('not available')
```

- The 2nd is to set `actual_price` to "not available", so it prints not available next to 'Product actual price'. To make this work you just need to add `actual_price = 'not found'` in your except block, so your code would become:

```py
    try:
        ap = container.find_all('strike', id = 'price')
        actual_price = ap[0].text

    except:
        print('not available')
        actual_price = 'not found'
```

Comment: Hey @Berlm thank you for your help, I guess second one works perfect and first one is deleting all the data as a particular element is missing. So I would go with second suggestion. Thank you for your help.